# Port-forwarding: different ports in router log?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, home-server, minecraft

My friend cannot connect to my minecraft server.

## How do the the different ports shown in my router's log affect port forwarding? What can I change to allow my friend connect to my server?

I believe I have done every necessary step to port forward, yet external devices cannot connect to my computer when the server is running and "whatsmyip.org" port-checking tools say port 25565 has timed-out.

My **router's log shows some interesting information** but I do not know what the next step is:

```
[LAN access from remote] from fr.iends.external.ip:60051 to 192.168.1.251:25565, Wednesday, Jan 15,2014 18:59:14
[LAN access from remote] from fr.iends.external.ip:60001 to 192.168.1.251:25565, Wednesday, Jan 15,2014 18:58:53
[LAN access from remote] from fr.iends.external.ip:59999 to 192.168.1.251:25565, Wednesday, Jan 15,2014 18:58:39
[LAN access from remote] from 204.11.33.59:52803 to 192.168.1.251:25565, Wednesday, Jan 15,2014 18:55:43
[LAN access from remote] from 204.11.33.59:52795 to 192.168.1.251:25565, Wednesday, Jan 15,2014 18:55:32
[LAN access from remote] from 204.11.33.59:52790 to 192.168.1.251:25565, Wednesday, Jan 15,2014 18:55:11
[LAN access from remote] from 204.11.33.59:52789 to 192.168.1.251:25565, Wednesday, Jan 15,2014 18:55:06
[LAN access from remote] from fr.iends.external.ip:59774 to 192.168.1.251:25565, Wednesday, Jan 15,2014 18:54:45
[LAN access from remote] from fr.iends.external.ip:59763 to 192.168.1.251:25565, Wednesday, Jan 15,2014 18:54:40
```

My router is the Nighthawk R7000 and I am using the Genie interface. The attempted connections are from two external devices to my server hosting device. One connection is from my friends ip and the other is from "whatsmyip.org". Notice that the port numbers are different between my LAN server device and whatsmyip.org. Also notice that the port number from the incoming external ip is not the same every time.

Neither google searches nor other Q/As have been helpful.
To make this post more informative, here is a link to [an imgur album containing my router's port-forwarding configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y60js.jpg) and a list of computer and router specifics:

- I am running Windows 7 and the "minecraft_server.1.7.4.exe" server application
- I have reserved a static IP for my LAN device running the server
- I can access the internet with all devices inside my LAN
- I successfully pinged my router using whatsmyip.org
- I have UPnP enabled
- My friend cannot connect from outside our network :(

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried turning off your windows firewall, or giving access to minecraft to allow the software to use that port?

Comment: How do I give access to minecraft to use the port 25565? Windows firewall is disabled.